# Аудио — плеер с нужными возможностями?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, плеер

Здравствуйте!
Нужен плеер (желательно что то вроде jplayer) с возможностью задать следующие ограничения воспроизведения:
Пауза / воспроизведение (без кнопки стоп), запрет перемотки - но это мелочь и реализовать я её могу в том же jplayer

А вот другое - Воспроизведение только 2 раза.
Может кто подскажет как можно это решить?

Answer (score 2):

```
ended : function(){

}
```

Вот в том же jplayer события есть же=)